# Cannot reference sheet through sheet number/codename

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in my vba when referencing some specific sheets number/codename. See below this working:

`Sheet37.Range("A3:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = False`

But this is not working:

`Sheet10.Range("A6:A14").EntireRow.Hidden = False`

For some reason, Excel can't reference this sheet and a few others, while I have no problem with most of the sheets in the workbook. Morever, I have retrieved a previous version from my file where the exact same code works totally fine.

I really do not see a reason as to why this would happen so any help is more than welcomed.

I also tried the following code within the sheet and it still does not work:

```
Sub Newfunction()
    Sheet10.Range("A6:A14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance

[Screenshot from running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Y8d.png)

(Note that I manually blurred some sheet names)

Comment: Do you actually have a `Sheet10`? What is the error that occurs?

Comment: Yes I have a sheet10! The error is "ActiveX component can't create object". (Run-time error '429')

Comment: The error message suggests that it's another line of code that's throwing the error, one containing `CreateObject`. Please share that line.

Comment: I'm quite confident the error is caused by this line, as it is the one higlighted when debugging and there is no more error when I remove it.

Comment: Does `Sheet10` contain any code in its code module?

Comment: No, I tried to put the formula "Range("A6:A14").EntireRow.Hidden = False" (sorry not sure how to format the code) in it and it throws the same error

Comment: Also in the VB Editor, under Tools > Options > General > Error Trapping, select Break in Class Module. Also, do you have any Excel add-ins installed and active?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I did the manipulation but it didn't seem to change anything. I do have add-ins though, but on other files I do not have the problem so not sure if they may cause it.

Comment: Try doing it manually while recording a macro.

Comment: Why don't you share a screenshot of the expanded [Project Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-project-explorer) window of the workbook so we can see that `Sheet10` exists (it should be the name **not** in parentheses e.g. `Sheet10(Data)`). Also, add the complete (relevant) code as text. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72491314/edit) at any time.

Comment: Hi! First thanks for your precious answers. I ran the macro and it worked, as it does not need to refer to sheet10 (@EEM). Regarding the project explorer, I promise the sheet does exist (I don't know how to post a picture in comment), and the code is really as simple as shown above (@VBasic2008). It just seems that I cannot refer to my sheet through the code name, though it works if I use the exact name.

Comment: It is possible that your workbook is corrupt, and that corruption is affecting only some of the sheets.  Regarding adding a screen shot, edit it into your question (because you only have 1 rep, it won't display, but the link will be there so we can see it)

Comment: Run this code and show us the results from the Immediate Window  `Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print "Index = " & ws.Index, "Name = |" & ws.Name & "|", "Code Name =|" & ws.CodeName & "|"
    Next
End Sub`

Comment: Ok yes maybe it is corrupted indeed. Would you have any idea on how to debug it? Or am I forced to rebuild the file? Anyway, please see in my original post a screenshot from running your code. We can see the sheet does exist and is referred so it is quite strange.

Comment: OK! I just repaired the file and it seems to work! Guess I should always start by doing that from now on! Thanks for all the answers, I really appreciate it